# Sometimes chromedriver gives error: stale element not found

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, element

Sometimes chromedriver gives error:
taleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.126)

In my tests  am using Robotframework. For code:
Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${new_btn}
Click Button                     ${new_btn}

Not always but from time to time I have an error like in the beginning.  So Wait keyword is passed always, but Click Button gives an error.
Is it a driver issue?

Driver is updated and first try was with the same error. Second is ok